# Android native app to open web app

Tags: android, web-applications, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm looking for the easiest solution to the following scenario:
I've developed a web app.
I need to send an sms with link+parameters for a unique user's registration.
BUT I want the link to direct to a native app installation that will install an app icon on home screen, and all this native app has to do is open the link to the web app.
By that I can avoid the Awkward solution of using bookmarks in android.
I know nothing about mobile app programming, so by easiest I mean: Either very basic tutorial, or a working native app that I can just change the URL and resubmit it as a new Native app.
or Any other easy suggestion